# Cant use prop as computed value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I run into a dead end.
I have a parent component that passes a prop to its child.

```
<v-data-table
  :items="prods"
  :hide-default-footer="true"
  hide-actions
  :headers="headers"
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <MyRow
      :props="props"
      :weight="line[props.item.related_id]['weight']"
    />
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

my child is this:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div>
        <v-text-field
          single-line
          hide-details
          clearable
          disabled
          @blur="update"
          v-model="measuredWeight"
        />
          </span>
      </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Component logic in child:

```
measuredWeight () {
  return this.weight.length
  // return this.weight.reduce((prevVal, currentVal) => prevVal + currentVal, initValue)
}
```

When the property gets changed in the parent this gets reflected in the children in terms that I can see the updated array.
However, neither the watcher on the property is triggered nor can I use the property in a computed. Wether using `this.$set()` or `Vue.set` or just pushing to the array in the parent doesnt really matter.

Any idea what I am missing ?

Comment: Can you share your component logic?

Comment: Have you tried to use `deep: true` option for the watcher?

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero I updated my question. my problem is that the change is somehow detected on my child (if i just let the v-model be weight it shows the correct updated array) but I cant detect the change in a watcher despite deep

Comment: Are you passing a function in v-model's child component? You should share more logic, I can't guess what `measuredWeight` is. I think you're having an issue implementing v-model in a custom component. This link could guide you https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero solved it. issue was the measuredWeight array was not observable.